# File Upload field using ActiveForm in Yii2 framework does not work

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

I want to add a File Upload field in an ActiveForm in Yii2 framework, but it's not working, the file is not uploaded nor the name of the file is stored in the database column 'company_cover'.

If someone could help me find my mistake. 
Thanks in advance.

The VIEW

```
 <div class="block-body collapse" id="company-block">
                            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                                'id'        => 'form-change-company',
                                'method'    => 'post',
                                'action'    => ['account/update-company'],
                                'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                                'options'   => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
                            ]); 


                            ?>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelAbout, 'group_id', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->dropDownList([2 => t('app','Enable'), 1 => t('app','Disable')])->label(false);
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'store_name', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Store Name'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'company_name', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company Name'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'company_mail', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company E-Mail'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'company_no', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company No'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'vat', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','VAT'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                                <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'company_lat', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company Latitude'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'company_lng', [
                                        'template'      => '{input} {error}',
                                    ])->textInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company Longitude'), 'class' => ''])->label(false); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                                <?= $form->field($modelCompany, 'file')->fileInput([ 'placeholder' => t('app','Company Cover'), 'class' => '']) ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <button type="submit" id="submit-company-info" class="btn-as" value="Submit"><?=t('app','Submit');?></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

The MODEL

```
class CustomerStore extends \app\models\auto\CustomerStore
{
    // when inactive model
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 'inactive';

    // when active model
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 'active';

    // when deactivated
    const STATUS_DEACTIVATED = 'deactivated';

    public $file;
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['store_name', 'company_name', 'company_mail', 'company_lat', 'company_lng', 'company_no', 'vat'], 'trim'],
            [['store_name', 'company_name'], 'required'],
            [['file'], 'file'],
            [['store_name', 'company_name'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['company_no', 'vat'], 'string', 'max' => 20],

            [['status'], 'safe']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

        $behaviors[] = [
            'class'     => SluggableBehavior::className(),
            'value' => [$this, 'getSlug'] //https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7773
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::attributeLabels(), [
            'store_id'      => t('app', 'Store ID'),
            'customer_id'   => t('app', 'Customer'),
            'store_name'    => t('app', 'Store Name'),
            'company_name'  => t('app', 'Company Name'),
            'company_mail'  => t('app', 'Company E-Mail'),
            'company_no'    => t('app', 'Company No'),
            'vat'           => t('app', 'VAT'),
            'status'        => t('app', 'Status'),
            'company_lat'   => t('app', 'Company Latitude'),
            'company_lng'   => t('app', 'Company Longitude'),
            'company_cover' => t('app', 'Company Cover'),
            'created_at'    => t('app', 'Created At'),
            'updated_at'    => t('app', 'Updated At'),
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCustomer()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Customer::className(), ['customer_id' => 'customer_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deactivate()
    {
        $this->status = self::STATUS_INACTIVE;
        $this->save(false);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function activate()
    {
        if($this->status == self::STATUS_DEACTIVATED || $this->status == self::STATUS_INACTIVE) {
            $this->status = self::STATUS_ACTIVE;
            $this->save(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @param $slug
     * @return array|null|\yii\db\ActiveRecord
     */
    public function findBySlug($slug)
    {
        return $this->find()->where(array(
            'slug' => $slug,
        ))->one();
    }

    /**
     * @param $event
     * @return string
     * //https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/7773
     */
    public function getSlug($event)
    {
        if(!empty($event->sender->slug)) {
            return $event->sender->slug;
        }
        return Inflector::slug($event->sender->store_name);
    }
}
```

The CONTROLLER (the controller is quite long so i just paste the part for the file upload field)

```
 public function actionUpload()
{
    $modelCompany = new CustomerStore();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $modelCompany->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($modelCompany, 'file');

        if ($modelCompany->validate()) {                
            $modelCompany->file->saveAs('/' . $modelCompany->file->baseName . '.' . $modelCompany->file->extension);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('upload', ['model' => $modelCompany]);
}
```

Comment: You get any errors in upload? What is the result of `UploadedFile::getInstance($modelCompany, 'file')`?

Comment: I do not get any errors, it runs and returns a SUCCESS message

Comment: Do you get the name of the file if you `var_dump($modelCompany->file);` ?

Comment: probably you don't have write permissions to `'/' . $modelCompany->file->baseName . '.' . $modelCompany->file->extension`

Comment: `var_dump($modelCompany->file->saveAs('/' . $modelCompany->file->baseName . '.' . $modelCompany->file->extension));` and verify if it returns `true` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must to load post data to the model. You can try do like this

```
if ($modelCompany->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $modelCompany->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($modelCompany, 'file');

    if ($modelCompany->validate()) {                
        $modelCompany->file->saveAs('/' . $modelCompany->file->baseName . '.' . $modelCompany->file->extension);
    }
}
```